# How to retrieve user access rights with FireDAC

Tags: mysql, delphi, permissions, firedac, sql-grant

I am using FireDAC to access a MySQL database from within Delphi.
When logging in into the database I give in the database user name, which is defined within MySQL and has certain access right.
How can I retrieve the access rights for this user from within Delphi/FireDAC? I want to make the menus tailored for the given rights. Now my application always allows a user to edit data where that user has no update rights. Then an exception is raised. But the user shouldn’t be allowed to edit in the first place.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you tried changing user rights in Delphi? MySQL may not be able to keep the user from editing data in your component.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement to see the access rights for the current user is

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;
```

however this is not supported by FireDAC.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-grants.html

Comment: To my understanding the OP wanted to restrict access, not see if access is restricted?

Comment: `How can I retrieve the access rights for this user from within Delphi/FireDAC?` - here, retrieve means read

Comment: My sincerest apologies. I must have read the question wrong.